# UIDocumentPickerViewController is dismissing parent view controller

Tags: ios, swift, dismiss, uidocumentinteraction

I am using UIDocumentPickerViewController, whenever I press done on the presented UIDocumentPickerViewController the screen is dismissing parent screen.

Thnak you!!

Comment: I don't want to dismiss the parent View controller

Comment: You need to provide code if you want us to help you.